# A-frame repeating an entity

Tags: aframe

Hi I'm trying to create 100 boxes like:
"a-box color="#999999" depth="0.5" height="2.5" width="2" position="0 1.25 -5""

at regular intervals in A-frame. Is there an easier way to do this than creating each one individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the [template component](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/template), but I'd recommend to try out creating a [custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html)!

You can create dynamically the `<a-box>`es in a custom component:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // define a custom component
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      // create 25 boxes on a 10x10 grid
      for (var row = 0; row <= 5; row += 0.5) {
        for (var col = 0; col <= 5; col += 0.5) {
          var box = document.createElement("a-box");
          box.setAttribute("color", "blue")
          box.setAttribute("scale", "0.1 0.1 0.1")
          // use the column / row for the position
          box.setAttribute("position", {
            x: 2.5 - col, y: 5 - row, z: -2
          })
          this.el.appendChild(box);
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene foo stats>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

---

Neat but super inefficient. Sooner then later the FPS will drop, and you may want to do this using the underlaying `THREE.js` API:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // define a custom component
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
      var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
      
      // create 25 boxes on a 10x10 grid
      for (var row = 0; row <= 5; row += 0.5) {
        for (var col = 0; col <= 5; col += 0.5) {
          var box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
          box.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
          box.position.set(2.5 - col, 5 - row, -2)
          this.el.object3D.add(box);
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene foo stats>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

---

Also stuff like "100" boxes sounds like [Instanced Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh). Check out the performance difference between [HTML elements](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/d3js/aframe.html) vs [instanced meshes](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/d3js/instanced.html)